# Procedure from Firebird to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, firebird

I need to create stored-procedure which returns one row for every week between two dates. I create this procedure in Firebird, but I can't achieve the same thing in SQL Server 2012.

I try to use Stored-procedure, but it cannot be called from select statement (I need to use result in union with another query)

I try to use function, but it return only one (last) value (week).

How can I rewrite this stored procedure for SQL Server 2012?

```
begin
TydenT = StartDate;
  while (TydenT < EndDate)
  do begin
  for select first 1
            EXTRACT(YEAR from cast(ib_datetostring(:TydenT, 'dd.mm.yyyy') as date)),
            EXTRACT(WEEK from cast(ib_datetostring(:TydenT, 'dd.mm.yyyy') as date))
        from SecurityUsers
  into :Rok, :Tyden
  do
    begin
    suspend;
    end
        TydenT = TydenT + 7;
        end
end
```

`StartDate` and `EndDate` are input parameters. `Rok` and `Tyden` are output paramaters and `TydenT` are variable.

EDIT.
If I use (41952 and 41975 are date in float)

```
select
    *
from StoredProcedure(41952, 41975)
```

then I want to get:

[image: Result]

Comment: I honestly have some trouble understanding what it is you want to do. Maybe you could try to explain the desired result given some sample input?

Comment: I add result which I expect.

Comment: Ok, It looks a lot like what you want is a sequence of week numbers between two given dates, is that it?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an user-defined function to do this.

This is just an example, it can almost certainly be written better, but it should given you an idea I hope. I used strings for input dates as I'm not sure how to convert the float dates (which I guess is a Firebird or Delphi thing).

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.getWeekNumbers (@StartDate date, @EndDate date)
RETURNS table
AS
RETURN (
    WITH cte (d) AS (
       SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, @StartDate) AS d
       UNION ALL
       SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, d) 
       FROM cte
       WHERE d < @EndDate
    )
    SELECT DISTINCT 
       DATEPART(year, d) AS y, 
       DATEPART(week, d) AS w 
    FROM cte
);
```

And call it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.getWeekNumbers('2014-10-01','2014-10-20')
```

Result:

```
y           w
----------- -----------
2014        40
2014        41
2014        42
2014        43
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is very helpfull and I thanks to you I resolve my problem. But I have two questions:
1, From any reason, this function always skip first week of year. Do you know why?
2, It's possible to get more then 100 rows (due to recursive way)?
Thanks for you answer :-)

Comment: 1. The first week I get is 1 for '2014-01-01' which seems to be correct, so I'm not sure what you are referring to. 2. `SELECT * FROM dbo.getWeekNumbers('2014-01-01','2014-10-20') OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)` will let you do more than 100 levels of recursion.